# Fresh install of Windows 10, keeping intact partition with data

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ntfs, windows-installation

I have to install Windows 10 Pro in a bootable hard drive of about 1Tb (model WD10EARS), formatted like this: first an 850Gb NTFS partition with data, and then 150Gb of unallocated space. My aim is to install the copy of Windows 10 in the unallocated space, keeping untouched the partition with the data; is it possible?

(Edit: no operating system is currently installed on the disk)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Boot from the Windows 10 installation media and follow instructions till it reaches on drive selection.

Don't select the partition with data.

Now select unallocated space and click view (if not available click advanced tools).

This will take you to the wizard to create a new drive from this space. (Make sure to format it as NTFS while creating the drive)

When created format the new drive and select it and click next to proceed.

And you're done.